# Unresolved reference: DaggerApplicationComponent

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

For some reason Dagger doesn't generate DaggerApplicationComponent for my component. I tried: rebuilding, cleaning, invalidating cache, restarting Android Studio and etc. Nothing worked for me.
Here is the full code:

Modules

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(): Context = provideContext()
}

@Module
class DatabaseModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    open fun provideRoom(context: Context): RoomDatabase =
        Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            AppDatabase::class.java,
            DATABASE_NAME
        ).build()
}

@Module
class NetworkModule {

    private val json = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }
    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(TokenInterceptor)
        .build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    open fun provideRetrofit(): Retrofit =
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(json.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType()))
            .client(client)
            .build()
}
```

Component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, DatabaseModule::class, NetworkModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun inject(defaultRepository: DefaultRepository)
    fun inject(myApplication: MyApplication)
}
```

Also in build.gradle file i use

```
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.35.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.35.1' // if you use the support libraries
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.35.1'

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlinx-serialization'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

Application

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
   val myApplication = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().build()
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code of Application?

Comment: Added it to original post

Comment: I think you forgot to add `kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.x` in `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Dagger Android, it seems that the way you inject the app module into the application is wrong.

Please correct it as follows:

In the app component, you should extend from `AndroidInjector`, specifically as follows:

*app_component.kt*

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, DatabaseModule::class, NetworkModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {

    @Component.Factory
    abstract class Factory : AndroidInjector.Factory<MyApplication>
}
```

Next is `MyApplication`. When you use dagger android, you should extend from `DaggerApplication()`. Just like that:

*my_application.kt*

```
class MyApplication : DaggerApplication() {

   override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(this)
    }
}
```

And finally, you should clean and rebuild your project.

And one more thing, make sure you add all the Dagger android libraries.

*app build.gradle.kts*

```
plugins {
    id("kotlin-kapt")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger:2.37")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.37")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.37")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.37")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.37")
}
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot. I didn't know that there are two versions: standard and for android. I replaced my dagger implementation to standard one and everything works good now! Should i try now to switch onto android specific version?

Comment: @EvgenyYurin 
With the android version, Dagger will better support Android. You can replace the origin version with the Android version. Or another option is Hilt. It's simpler than Dagger and supports well with Android components like content provider, service, .... You should try Hilt. More information: [Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android?authuser=3)